# factory normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The number of workers in a factory distributes $N(100,7^2)$.

A factory is considered big when it has more than $110$ workers.
Considered small when it has less than $80$ workers and is considered mediocre with $80-110$ workers. I need to calculate the probability for each of this cases.

What I did was,

$P(B>110)=1-P(B<=110)=1-0.9235$
$P(B<80)=P((B-100)/7<-20/7)=1-0.99786$
$P(80<B<110)=0.0765-0.00214=0.07436$

I'm still trying to grasp the whole normal distribution thing and am pretty sure that I did somethings wrong or used the table wrong with the negetive values, would love to get some feedback to wether what I did was correct and wether these answers are applicable final answers or am I supposed to do something in addition.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last one is wrong

$$\mathbb{P}[80\leq X\leq 110]=\Phi\Bigg[\frac{110-100}{7}\Bigg]-\Phi\Bigg[\frac{80-100}{7}\Bigg]=0.9234-0.0021\approx 92.13\%$$

The sum of the three probabilities has to be 1:

$$7.66\%+0.21\%+92.13\%=100\%$$

Answer (score 1):

Does this figure help you understand the integrals?

[image]

Comment: it does thank you